# Resize logo in nav bar on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm learning all of this on the fly, so I'm hoping you can help me figure it out. I've added my logo to the nav bar as a background image on a blank menu item (maybe a clunky method, but the best solution I could find). It works great for desktop views but I'm not sure how to make it resize in my mobile menu.

You can see the actual site here: http://www.christinelellis.com

Thanks!
Christine

Comment: nevermind, i was looking at your image instead of your logo

Comment: @christine-lellis On *StackOverflow* when people help you by answering to your questions, usually you give them at least some feedback to let them know that their answer was useful and to respect the time they spend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is not real question and as I don't know how this is build, here is how I would fix this:

On the menu, I would add some `overflow: hidden` on the list items (not very necessary but at least if you keep it like this, the other *buttons* are not overrided by the image and it's still functional.):

```
#menu-main-menu li {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

and **then** make the logo link *fluid* with a real image (`<img>`) in the link instead of having the logo image set as `background` (and this is **a lot** better in term of *SEO* to have an *image* with a proper *alt* text instead of a `background-image`) :

**HTML**

```
<li id="menu-item-4025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-3215 current_page_item menu-item-4025">
    <a href="http://www.christinelellis.com/">
        <img src="http://www.christinelellis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/main-logo-small.png" alt="christine lellis logo"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

then in **CSS**:

```
#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-4025 img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 300px;
   width: auto;
}
```

You'll have to remove the *CSS* on the `a` link which define a fixed *width* and a fixed *height* and which kick the text to `text-indent: -9999px;` (which is also really bad in term of **SEO**..).

This would be a good beginning.

Good Luck'

Comment: RedBreast, thanks for the suggestions. I realize my method was not an ideal solution for SEO or anything...it was just the best fix I could find within my capabilities. I'll play with this and see what I can do.And yes, of course I appreciate your time. I'm sure you can tell from the site, I'm a small biz owner- not a developer- so this is the first chance I've had to check back at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change a few things. First I would put the menu-control span inside the header at the top so it's all lined up. Then you can place your logo underneath. So it would look something like this:

```
 <div id="header" class="header">
      <span class="menu_control>Menu</span>
      // add in rest of the header you have here
 </div>
 <div class="nav_container">
     <div class="outerlogo">
         <div class="innerlogo">
             <img src"http://www.christinelellis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/main-logo-small.png" />
         </div>
     </div>
     // add rest of your html here
  </div>

  css:
  @media (max-width: 900px)
  .menu_control { width: 100%; border-width: 0; background-color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px; cursor: pointer; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; max-width: 100px; margin: auto 0px; float: left;

  .outerlogo { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-block; margin: auto 0px; padding: 0px; }

  .innerlogo { margin: auto 0px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; }

  .innerlogo img { width: 90%; max-width: 280px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: auto 0px; }
```

Also get rid of @media (max-width: 450px) .menu_control and .header, just use the min-width 900px for everything for mobile, or switch it to 610px, whatever you want to do. I used the img tag instead of a background-image since its easier to manipulate.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'm not sure how to do this since the @media settings are part of my theme...I'm going to try the solution above but I really appreciate your time :)

Answer (score -1):

You can resize a background image using the [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property.

To target the smaller (mobile) devices you'll need to use a [Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media) query to target those.

An example of this on your site would be:

```
/* smaller screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #menu-item-4025 a {
        ...
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: 70% 70%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
}
/* larger screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #menu-item-4025 a {
        ...
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Note** you'll need to change the 320px/768px break points based on your current media queries, but that should get you started.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes? This solves the problem described without getting the OP to rewrite their code. Of course I might code it differently using an img instead of background image etc. but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Thanks DAC84. I understand why the others mentioned I should use an img instead of background image but this seems like a fairly easy workaround (that's how I ended up with the background image in the first place- fast, easy, and I could make it work). I know that's not always the *best* solution, but I'm new to all this...! Learning as I go.